# list[0:9] and list[0:10] have same values

Tags: python

`list[0:9]` and `list[1:10]` were showing same in my python IDLE. I'm not sure the logic behind, could some one please explain. Please see the values retrieved below.

```
>>> list[0:9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list[0:10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

[image]

Comment: Well there are only 9 elements in your list. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: >>> list[0:5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list[0:6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list[0:7]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list[0:8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list[0:9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list[0:10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Comment: But that didn't answer my question. Your original list contains only nine elements. What do you want to happen when you ask for the tenth?

Comment: every time in result i see values up to the end element,
this is not happening with list[0:10]

Comment: For the third time **you only have nine elements to start with**. Where are you expecting the tenth to come from?

Comment: I'm expecting to see up to number 10 when i give list[0:10]

Comment: @sivamallikarjun how many elements are there in `list`?

Comment: I understood. Sorry, There were 9 elements in list. Daniel, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latter the second index is over the last element.

```
l = [1,2,3]
l[0:100]
=> [1,2,3]
```